# Need Help Converting Large Numbers with negative exponents in node

Tags: javascript, node.js, sqlite, twitch

Hello so I am trying to make a twitch bot that can handle really large numbers for users to convert to chips for a casino so the conversion is 1 chip = 100Billion points but everytime I try to write this to a file I get NaN , all users balances are stored in their own text file and are updated when they transfer their points

```
    var bigInt = require("big-integer");
    if (message.endsWith('twitchbotsnamehere') && tags.username === 'botsusername'){
     const usersplit = message.split(' '); 
     var twitchUser = usersplit[0];
     fs.readFile(twitchUser+".txt", "UTF8", function(err, data) {
         if (err) { throw err };
         
         var chipTrans = Number(usersplit[3]);
         var userBal = Number(data);
         var chipAmt = Number(chipTrans/bigInt(1).pow(-11));
         
         var tempBal = (userBal + chipAmt);
       fs.writeFile(twitchUser+".txt", tempBal.toString(), 'utf8' ,  (err) => {
         if (err) throw err;
          console.log('User Balance Updated!');
});
         client.say(channel,  `@${twitchUser}, Chips have been added to your account!` )

         //client.say(channel, `@${tags.username}, Current Balance is: ` + userBal);
});
     
 }
```

Comment: Why did you tag `java`?

Comment: because node is written in JS

Comment: Oh, and JS is? @swiftgaming